# Gradient vector proof

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-derivative

**Question:**

> Prove that a normal vector to the surface $f(x,y) = \sqrt {xy}$ at any point on the surface is perpendicular to the line joining the point to the origin.

I am not sure how to do this. I have found the gradient vector but what do I do now?

Comment: So what is the gradient vector?

Comment: It may be of interest that this exercise generalizes: It is true for _any_ $f(x,y)=x^a y^b$ with $a+b=1/2$ and any linear combination of such functions.

Answer (score 2):

Find the normal vector in terms of $x$ and $y$. Then show $\vec{n} \cdot  (x, y, \sqrt{xy}) = 0$. If the dot product is 0, then the two vectors are orthogonal, "perpendicular".

Answer (score 0):

As $f(x,y) = \sqrt {xy}$ then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) = \frac{y}{2\sqrt{xy}}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) = \frac{x}{2\sqrt{xy}}$. The normal vector at a certain point $p_0 = (x_0, y_0)$ is given by $$N(p_0) = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p_0),\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p_0),-1\right)$$

A line that passes through the origin and $p_0$ (surface) is given by

$$r(t) = tv_0 $$

where $v_0= (p_0, \sqrt{x_0y_0})$. Then you need to check if $N(p_0) \cdot v_0 = 0$.